# I can't track failed insert queries on CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've been troubleshooting for a while now and have found no solution. I'm trying to insert records using active records on codeigniter, but I wanted to give users feedback on failed queries but I have failed to track failed queries. Failed insert queries stops other queries from being processed. Here are my codes....

```
       $this->db->insert('table_name', $data);
       $errors=$this->db->_error_message();

       if(!empty($errors)){
           return false;
       }else{
           return true;
       }
```

Any assistance will be appreciated!

Comment: This is why failed database operations should throw Exceptions.

Comment: Perhaps you need `$db['default']['db_debug'] = true;` and thats why you are unable to get last error?

Comment: As you're inserting, you could just return the insert_id which will return null if nothing is inserted.

Answer (score 0):

You should do this way

```
return $this->db->insert('table_name', $data);
```

OR

```
if($this->db->insert('table_name', $data)){
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```